# Software to perform CRUD operation on database table

Tags: web-apps, database

I currently use postgres and sqlserver database to manage our data and perform query on it. I have developed JSF application on top of it to perform crud operations. But there are requirement to add more tables and I need to perform development to load csv into it and perfrom CRUD. Are there any application that can do this? This tool will act on top of my database as a GUI to end user.

Comment: phpmyadmin? SQLyog?

Comment: CRUD gui is what I ma asking about.